# Loopback timestamp conversion issue

Tags: postgresql, loopback, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table that contains a timestamp column. whenever I try to access the endpoint it returns timestamp data as UTC timestamp. I want the timestamp data without UTC conversion.

Comment: Please post the `CREATE` statement of the table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE sample_table(
  id TEXT not null default id_generator()  PRIMARY KEY,
  tag text,
  "timestamp" timestamptz NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL 
);